# Convert number inside a string to english words

Tags: python

I'm currently working on neural text to speech, and to process the data I need several steps. One step is convert the numeric in string into english character words instead of numeral. The closest thing I can found is `num2words`, but I'm not sure how to apply it to an existing string. Here's my use case :

I have list of string like this

```
list_string = ['I spent 140 dollar yesterday','I have 3 brothers and 2 sisters']
```

I wanted to convert into :

```
output_string = ['I spent one hundred forty dollar yesterday','I have three brothers and two sisters']
```

The struggle is one text might consist of several number, and even if I can get the numeric using `re.match`, I'm not sure how to put the number back to the string.

No need to worry about floating number or year for now since I don't have that kind of number inside my string.

Thanks

Comment: @Julien I already read the github, and the pip landing page before raising this question. I don't find any documentation for such libary, or can you point me if i missed it? thanks

Comment: @VinsonCiawandy people are downvoting because you basically give them an assignment. "I have this, now provide me with my code pls." You should show what you have tried and were you get stuck.

Comment: That's weird, I have asked 17 questions before and pretty sure have the same format and never have problems with it. I already try googling for closest answer I can get is `num2words`, which is not enough for me to solve my problems. If that doesn't count as my effort, then should I try to throw gibberish code that doesn't worked in OP so it will add more time for the reader of my question ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a very quick way to do it in one line using regex to match digits and replace them in string:

```
from num2words import num2words
import re

list_string = ['I spent 140 dollar yesterday','I have 3 brothers and 2 sisters']
output_string = [re.sub('(\d+)', lambda m: num2words(m.group()), sentence) for sentence in list_string]
```

Otherwise, you can iterate through the words contained in each sentence and replace them in case they are numbers. Please see the code below:

```
from num2words import num2words

list_string = ['I spent 140 dollar yesterday','I have 3 brothers and 2 sisters']
output_string = []

for sentence in list_string:
    output_sentence = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word.isdigit():
            output_sentence.append(num2words(word))
        else:
            output_sentence.append(word)
    output_string.append(' '.join(output_sentence))

print(output_string)

# Output
# ['I spent one hundred and forty dollar yesterday', 'I have three brothers and two sisters']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is my first time reading about using lambda expression inside the `re.sub` and your answer works very well.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried it doing it in bash, the script looks like this.
file name be conver2words.sh , invoke this from your python script.

```
digits=(
    "" one two three four five six seven eight nine
    ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eightteen nineteen
)
tens=("" "" twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety)
units=("" thousand million billion trillion)

number2words() {
    local -i number=$((10#$1))
    local -i u=0
    local words=()
    local group

    while ((number > 0)); do
        group=$(hundreds2words $((number % 1000)) )
        [[ -n "$group" ]] && group="$group ${units[u]}"

        words=("$group" "${words[@]}")

        ((u++))
        ((number = number / 1000))
    done
    echo "${words[*]}"
}

hundreds2words() {
    local -i num=$((10#$1))
    if ((num < 20)); then
        echo "${digits[num]}"
    elif ((num < 100)); then
        echo "${tens[num / 10]} ${digits[num % 10]}"
    else
        echo "${digits[num / 100]} hundred $("$FUNCNAME" $((num % 100)) )"
    fi
}

with_commas() {
    # sed -r ':a;s/^([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})/\1,\2/;ta' <<<"$1"
    # or, with just bash
    while [[ $1 =~ ^([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})(.*) ]]; do
        set -- "${BASH_REMATCH[1]},${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    done
    echo "$1"
}

for arg; do
    [[ $arg == *[^0-9]* ]] && result="NaN" || result=$(number2words "$arg")
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$(with_commas "$arg")" "$result"
done
```

In action:

```
$ bash ./num2text.sh 9 98 987 
9       nine
98      ninety eight
987     nine hundred eighty seven
```

you can check if the string has the number and call this script to get the words of it.

Adding the python code for this, this is a draft you will get an idea

```
list_string = ['I spent 140 dollar yesterday','I have 3 brothers and 2 sisters']

for str in list_string:
    str_split = str.split(" ");
    for word in str_split: 
        if word.isnumeric():
           // now you know this is numberic and call the bash script from here and read the output you can also use os.system if it works instead of sub process
           out = subprocess.call(['bash','conver2words.sh',word])
           line = out.stdout.readline()
           print(line);
            
        else:
            print(word);
```

Comment: Sorry bro, but have you ready my question correctly? I already make it simple and straight to the point. The main problem is I don't know the location of the number in the text

Comment: Hope this edit is use full, I thought you can identify it by is numeric method and can call this script to get the words of the number. Hope this helps

Comment: few minor changes you might need as per your requirement. I am trying to give you an approach.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time reading isnumeric method on a string and sure I understand your approach. I can modify it to suit my use case.

Comment: If is helps you to achieve what you are trying to do. I will be happy and this is my first answer by the way:)